# Watermark Over Figures - Watermark only appears on first two pages of my document

Tags: watermark

I want to add a watermark to my document but it only keeps showing up on my title page and one of my table of contents page, and I just want it on my chapters but it's not work. I tried this:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{report}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc} % Para caracteres en español
\usepackage{amsmath,amsthm,amsfonts,amssymb,amscd}
\usepackage{multirow,booktabs}
\usepackage[table]{xcolor}
\usepackage{fullpage}
\usepackage{lastpage}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\usepackage{mathrsfs}
\usepackage{wrapfig}
\usepackage{setspace}
\usepackage{calc}
\usepackage{multicol}
\usepackage{cancel}
\usepackage[retainorgcmds]{IEEEtrantools}
\usepackage[margin=3cm]{geometry}
\newlength{\tabcont}
\setlength{\parindent}{0.0in}
\setlength{\parskip}{0.05in}
\usepackage{empheq}
\usepackage{framed}
\usepackage[most]{tcolorbox}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\parindent 0in
\parskip 12pt
\geometry{margin=1in, headsep=0.25in}
\theoremstyle{definition}
\newtheorem{defn}{Definition}
\newtheorem{reg}{Rule}
\newtheorem{exer}{Exercise}
\newtheorem{note}{Note}
\usepackage{textgreek}
\usepackage{easytable}
\usepackage[official]{eurosym}
\usepackage{array}


\usepackage{hyperref}
\hypersetup{
    colorlinks=true,
    linkcolor=blue,
    citecolor=blue,
    pdftitle={Maths O-Level Notes}}


\pagenumbering{arabic}
\thispagestyle{empty}


\usepackage{titlesec}
\titleformat{\chapter}{\normalfont\LARGE\bfseries}{\thechapter}{1em}{}
\titleclass{\chapter}{straight}

\renewcommand{\thesection}{\arabic{section}}
\renewcommand{\thefigure}{\arabic{figure}}
\renewcommand{\thetable}{\arabic{chapter}.\arabic{table}}
\newtheorem{theorem}{Theorem}
\newcolumntype{C}[1]{>{\centering\let\newline\\\arraybackslash\hspace{0pt}}m{#1}} % for centering of table items
\newcolumntype{L}[1]{>{\raggedright\let\newline\\\arraybackslash\hspace{0pt}}m{#1}}
\newcolumntype{R}[1]{>{\raggedleft\let\newline\\\arraybackslash\hspace{0pt}}m{#1}}



\linespread{1.5} %line spacing


\usepackage[printwatermark]{xwatermark}
\usepackage{graphicx}

\newwatermark*[allpages,color=red!50,angle=45,scale=3,xpos=0,ypos=0]{CT PRIVATE TUITION}


\begin{document}
\begin{titlepage}
    \begin{center}
        \vspace*{1cm}
        \Huge
        \textbf{Maths O-Level}\\
        \vspace{0.7cm}
        \Huge
        MATSEC Notes \\
        \vspace{1.2cm}
        \includegraphics[width=0.4\textwidth]{images/calc.jpg}\\
        \vspace{2.5cm} 
        \textbf{Tuition} \\
        \Large
        \vspace{1.5cm}
        Compiled By: \\
        Giu[![enter image description here][1]][1] \\
        \vfill    
        \Large
        2023          
    \end{center}
    \end{titlepage}


\tableofcontents

\include{Year 9_Numbers.tex}
\include{Year 9_Algebra.tex}
\include{Year 9_Statistics and Data Handling.tex}
\include{O Level.tex}    
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thank you for providing the source code.  Can you try to simplify it (by only keeping the lines that reproduce the bug).  We want to answer your questions but we also want that future visitors can learn from old questions.

Comment: I'm not sure what the problem is, as no bug is appearing per se, I put down everything because that's my "main environment", I thought maybe there might be a clash of packages or maybe the structure is incorrect etc...

Comment: Please, delete several of the packages to isolate what you intend to do. Your minimal working example is too long. Also, search for similar questions on watermarks

Comment: note no one can use your example as they don't have `images/calc.jpg`  you can use `example-image` which is available for such tests, but you should also delete every package you can deletee while still showing the problem

Comment: We also don't have any of the files you `\include`. Try replacing them using `kantlipsum` or `lipsum`, packages which exist to fill examples with text.